# How do I define architecture arm64 when building the docker image through Maven spring-boot:build-image on Windows?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, intellij-idea

I have several Spring Boot microservices in one parent and I can run `spring-boot:build-image` to build docker images for all modules. I'm using my Windows WSL2 Ubuntu x86_64 and Docker Engine to build the images through the configuration in IntelliJ.

I'ts all fine and dandy on my Windows machine and I can start the containers successfull, but I want my images to run in containers on my Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Server 21.04 for architecture ARM64 and pull them through my Windows Docker Registry so I can easily transfer images locally. My registry works as well, but then I'm stuck with the error that the image cannot be started due to architecture problems.

**How can I change the architecture of the docker image build in the IntelliJ Maven configuration run?**

I've found the spring-boot configuration through Maven very convenient, it does all sorts of configuration for building the image. I don't know how to use docker-compose.yml or a Dockerfile to successfull build an image. If this is the answer I will focus my research on this, but up until now I'm quite stuck what to do.

My feeling goes towards the pom.xml and define any configuration there. My pom.xml looks like this right now:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Question edit*:
I have seen you can use the parameter `--platform=linux/arm64`. Can I put this somewhere?

Comment: Try to use Docker CLI to do this task. You can use --build-arg ARCH=arm64v8 in your build command. for more info, see this article please:
https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/

I hope this could help you

Comment: I get access denied with every manifest CLI I execute on my images on the docker engine.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to be one of the things I could not get running yet, until now - using a Dockerfile.

1. In IntelliJ I connect to my Docker remote Raspberry Pi instance on my local network through *Services*
2. I create a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

3. I choose Deploy on the Docker instance in IntelliJ and select the Dockerfile
4. It now builds and deploys my application on my Raspberry Pi without any local Windows services coming inbetween

Successfully build and deployed a Docker image and container through the Dockerfile running Deploy with IntelliJ! *I'm so happy*

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem isn't at the Maven build step but rather the Docker build step (which happens after you do a Maven build).

I was able to use Maven `spring-boot:build-image` followed by this Docker command to build an image for ARM arch:

`docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 --tag <username>/<image name>:<tag> .`

Adding a `--push` flag will automatically push the image to your registry when it's built.